# How to display a specific range of random numbers in java using Math.random

Tags: java, random, numbers

So, I am fairly new to programming and I started learning about Math.random. I am trying to code a program that will print values in between 4 - 12 but i can't seem to print only the values inside that range. It prints 13 which i don't want to

My Code:

```
public class MathRandom{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        for(int x = 0; x < 10; x++){ //Just to test what numbers are displayed
        System.out.println((int) (Math.random() * 10) + 4);

        }
    }
}
```

Did I miss something? thanks in advance for the help

Comment: Create an array of desired elements (4 - 12) and then select random index from it.

Int[] ArrayVariable = [4, 5, ..., 12];
random = from 0 to count of elements in ArrayVariable
system.out.println(ArrayVariable[random]);

Comment: google is your friend: ***4.710.000 results (0,59 Seconds)***

Comment: Bro, you must be blind. I asked how to generate ANY RANDOM NUMBER BETWEEN ANY TWO VALUES. NOT ARRAY!! It's COMPLETELY DIFFERENT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the line to this:-

```
System.out.println((int) (Math.random() * 9) + 4);
```

This will generate a random number from 0-8, and then add 4 to it, meaning the results will be from 4-12.

Comment: May I just ask, but why is it 9 instead of 10? Can you explain so that I can understand how it works?

Comment: 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 <--- 9 distinct values

Comment: `Math.random() * 9` generates the numbers 0-8 (i.e. one less than the 9).  `Math.random() * 10` generates the numbers 0-9.  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()  Note that there are better ways to get random numbers though.

Comment: OHHHH I GET IT NOW! How dumb of me to not notice. Thank you VERY much for telling me